# Problem sets for Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm taking a class in Discrete Math at the moment and our prescribed text doesn't have much in the way of problem sets and solutions so I'm finding it difficult to practice. Does anyone have any books/problem sets they recommend for Combinatorics practice?

Comment: You should probably ask your instructor.  S/he will give you problems that are more relevant to what you're working on in class.

Comment: Discrete math is an *enormous* subject, so you don't want to work on just any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the curriculum and the professor who teaches the course. The popular book is Intro to Discrete Math by K. Rosen formerly of Bell Labs. Nowadays, there are many more books by other authors. I would check this book online by Amazon to see if it is still in print and the cost, etc..